# How to get array like this in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have one Event array like this :

```
 Array (

     [0] = Array(
                  [EventId] => 596
                  [Event] => test
                  [ResourceId] => 6
                  [StartDate] =>  2013-06-21 10:00:00
                  [FinishDate]  2013-06-21 10:30:00                   
                )
     [1] = Array(
                  [EventId] => 598
                  [Event] => another test
                  [ResourceId] => 6
                  [StartDate] =>  2013-06-21 15:00:00
                  [FinishDate]  2013-06-21 16:30:00                   
                )
     [2] = Array(
                  [EventId] => 599
                  [Event] => test
                  [ResourceId] => 8
                  [StartDate] =>  2013-06-21 10:00:00
                  [FinishDate]  2013-06-21 10:30:00                   
                )
      [3] = Array(
                  [EventId] => 601
                  [Event] => another test
                  [ResourceId] => 10
                  [StartDate] =>  2013-06-21 15:00:00
                  [FinishDate]  2013-06-21 16:30:00                   
                )
      [4] = Array(
                  [EventId] => 602
                  [Event] => new event
                  [ResourceId] => 10
                  [StartDate] =>  2013-06-22 10:00:00
                  [FinishDate]  2013-06-22 12:30:00                   
                )
      [5] = Array(
                  [EventId] => 604
                  [Event] => try new event
                  [ResourceId] => 6
                  [StartDate] =>  2013-06-22 10:00:00
                  [FinishDate]  2013-06-22 12:30:00                   
                )
       )
```

And I want the result array from event array like this :

```
   Array (

     [0] = Array(
                  [EventId] => 596,599
                  [Event] => test
                  [ResourceId] => 6,8
                  [StartDate] =>  2013-06-21 10:00:00
                  [FinishDate]  2013-06-21 10:30:00                   
                )
     [1] = Array(
                  [EventId] => 598,601
                  [Event] => another test
                  [ResourceId] => 6,10
                  [StartDate] =>  2013-06-21 15:00:00
                  [FinishDate]  2013-06-21 16:30:00                   
                )         
     [2] = Array(
                  [EventId] => 602
                  [Event] => new event
                  [ResourceId] => 10
                  [StartDate] =>  2013-06-22 10:00:00
                  [FinishDate]  2013-06-22 12:30:00                   
                )
     [3] = Array(
                  [EventId] => 604
                  [Event] => try new event
                  [ResourceId] => 6
                  [StartDate] =>  2013-06-22 10:00:00
                  [FinishDate]  2013-06-22 12:30:00                   
                )
       )
```

I am working on PHP. But i don't know how to iterate array to match its 2 values and add into the new array.

I need to match StartDate and EndDate. If both are same than i need to concat resource id and merge that records.

I tried with for loop but it didn't work.

I've tried this :

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($event);$i++)
  {
if(($event[$i]["StartDate"]==$event[$i+1]["StartDate"]) && ($event[$i]["FinishDate"]==$event[$i+1]["FinishDate"]))
     {
     echo "yes"."<br>"; // Add in new array
     }
     else
     {
    echo "no"."<br>";
     }      
  }
```

Can anyone please help me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do not get what you are trying to achieve. Group events by event `name` | `by start date` | `by finish date`?

Comment: I want to match StartDate and EndDate. If both are same than i need to merge that records means want to concat that matching resource id. bcoz both resource are working at same time.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor : I've added my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like:

```
$out = array();
$c = count($event);
for ($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) {
    $out[$i] = $event[$i];
    for ($j = $i+1; $j < $c; $j++) {
        if ($event[$i]["StartDate"] == $event[$j]["StartDate"] && 
            $event[$i]["FinishDate"] == $event[$j]["FinishDate"]) {
            $out[$i]["EventId"] .= ", " . $event[$j]["EventId"];
            // do the same with other indices
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Multidimensional arrays! You will need nested for loops:

```
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
for($j=0;$j<4;$j++)
{
$var = $your_array[i][j];
echo $var;//do whatever you want to do with the variable here
}
}
```

Comment: I need to match StartDate and EndDate. If both are same than i need to concat resource id and merge that records.